# Android: Hide custom action bar icons

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an Activity with custom action bar, which has some icons on it.as of now this custom actionbar is common for all the fragments

But in one of my fragment i want to hide few icons .But when i am doing it on the fragment onActivtyCreated() method it is giving nullpointer exception.

**In my BaseActivity**

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(mCustomView);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

**In my Fragment**

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

How to hide the actionbar icons specific to the fragement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create method in activity like below

```
public void hideImageIcon(){
    ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

call this method from fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).hideImageIcon();
}
```

Comment: @AmitVaghela SO is asking to wait few minutes before accepting the answer.  Both Dhawal and ErShani answer works.

Answer (score 2):

you can access activity's components by

```
((YourActivity)getActivity()).imageView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using broadcast method is simple.
In baseActivity :

```
    IntentFilter filter1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        filter1 = new IntentFilter("hide_actoinbar");
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter1);
    }


    private final BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            hideActionbar(); // your method
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    }
```

In fragment :

```
 public void broadcastIntent()
    {
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setAction("hide_actoinbar");
       sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the visibility of your menu items you just need to  call invalidateOptionsMenu() and hide the items in your overridden onCreateOptionsMenu() method.

```
@Override 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{ 
    // inflate menu from xml 
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);

            for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++)
            menu.getItem(i).setVisible(false);

}
```